# How to pass value from one function to another?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to pass my current location coordinates from `func locationManager()` to my `func viewDidLoad()` how can I pass that ?

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var location=0
var latPass: Double!
var longPass: Double!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    var location=locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan=MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    var myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    latPass=location.coordinate.latitude
    longPass=location.coordinate.longitude
}
```

When I print my **lat** & **long** in the `func locationManager` I get the value, but when I print it in my `viewDidLoad()`, I get nil

Here is my `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(latPass)
    print(longPass)

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latPass, longitude: longPass)
    let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
    london.title = "You"
    london.tracksViewChanges=true
    london.icon = UIImage(named: "currentLocation.png")
    london.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker=london
}
```

I think I have to make a instance of the var, but I'm unable to find a way.

Comment: The code you have mentioned here are belongs to same class?

Comment: `didUpdateLocations` is a delegate method and it's called after you set the delegate

Comment: `didUpdateLocations` works asynchronously, put the `print` lines into the delegate method. And somewhere you have to set the delegate and tell the manager to retrieve the location

Comment: @GouravJoshi Yes, same class.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava so, how can I get the value in my `viewDidLoad()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewDidLoad` it is the first method called by view Controller and once it is called the other methods are also called. You need to set delegate in viewDidLOad class. These params during loading of view remains empty, but when the delegate method called it will store data and you will get it as per in method.

You need like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
}
```

And then this method executes its stuff:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    var location=locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan=MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    var myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    latPass=location.coordinate.latitude
    longPass=location.coordinate.longitude
    print(latPass)
    print(longPass)
    /// Here you can set the positioning managing stuff, because lat long are showing.
   let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latPass, longitude: longPass)
   let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
   london.title = "You"
   london.tracksViewChanges=true
   london.icon = UIImage(named: "currentLocation.png")
   london.map = mapView
   mapView.selectedMarker=london
}
```

Once method called you can see console for outputs.

Comment: I already have the `manager.delegate = self` in my code, I've updated my code. I want to pass my values in `position`, thats why I need `latPass` & `longPass`

Comment: Please mentioned what is position, so I can update my answer.

Comment: `let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latPass, longitude:longPass)`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you can't pass values to your `viewDidLoad` method like that because of viewDidLoad method call when loading of your view is finished and `didUpdateLocations` it's delegate method so it will take some time to call that's why you got **null**.

Still can't understand what you want to active. More elaborate with code so will help you.

Comment: Then you should write code in  didUpdateLocations and also call manager.stopUpdatingLocation() so didUpdateLocations will be not call again

Comment: yes, it works now, but what if I want my location to update continuously, because I'm making a tracking app.

Comment: Then you do not need to write manager.stopUpdatingLocation() in didUpdateLocations method